# dropDown HTML inside ag-grid column Headers using angual4

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How can I embed a drop down for column header in the ag-Grid using Angular?

If I have an employee grid with a a "type" column. The employee type has two options: permanent and contract. I need a dropdown for this in the column header.

Comment: you can write your own header component. See this link - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/

Comment: Thanks..i am able show drop down at column header but how can i apply filter like if i select full time show result of full time records

Comment: Check - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#filtering
and example for angular header component in this link
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#angular-header-component

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom filter component for that.

> Take a look at this live example: **[Plunk ag-grid custom filter component](https://plnkr.co/edit/iUrXZcG14lzhpD5Ofa3z?p=preview)**
>
> Check `EmployeeType` column in the Plunk.

1. Implement `IFilterAngularComp`
2. Implement required methods for this. i.e. `getModel`, `setModel`, `doesFilterPass`, `isFilterActive`, etc
3. Provide this component as filter component for the column definition.

Below is the code for the filter component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'filter-cell',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            EmployeeType Filter: 
            <select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="type" class="form-control">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
              <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
            </select>
        </div>`
    , styles: [.....]
})
export class RecordTypeFilter implements IFilterAngularComp {
    private params: IFilterParams;
    private valueGetter: (rowNode: RowNode) => any;

    @ViewChild('select', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public select;

    agInit(params: IFilterParams): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    }

    isFilterActive(): boolean {
        return this.type !== null && this.type !== undefined && this.type !== '';
    }

    doesFilterPass(params: IDoesFilterPassParams): boolean {
        return this.type.toLowerCase()
            .split(" ")
            .every((filterWord) => {
                return this.valueGetter(params.node).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) >= 0;
            });
    }

    getModel(): any {
        return {value: this.text};
    }

    setModel(model: any): void {
        this.type = model ? model.value : '';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(params: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //this.select.element.nativeElement.focus();
        })
    }

    // noinspection JSMethodCanBeStatic
    componentMethod(message: string): void {
        alert(`Alert from RecordTypeFilterComponent ${message}`);
    }

    onChange(newValue): void {
        if (this.type !== newValue) {
            this.type = newValue;
            this.params.filterChangedCallback();
        }
    }
}
```